# Running radare command on each line of the output of another command

Tags: radare2

Say, I have a command in radare which produces multiple input, say `afl`. I can run it and extract many addresses:

```
[0x5579ca2e2196]> afl~[0]
0x5579ca2e2060
0x5579ca2e4fe0
0x5579ca2e2090
0x5579ca2e20c0
0x5579ca2e2100
```

How do I do run another command on each of those addresses? Let's say I want to print first byte of each of them or set a breakpoint with `db` on each address.

I read about iteration, but it looks like it only works on flags with something like `sym.*`, but not on arbitrary outputs, so I can't do this:

```
p8 1 @@ `some command which produces many addresses`
```

I know that I can save output to a file and then use something like `p8 1 @@.my_file`, but it looks strange that I need to create a file for that.

Basically, I want a way to run a single radare command (possibly with parameters) for every line of output of another radare command.

Comment: Sounds like a job for xargs if for some reason that doesn't work, a bash while loop and if that doesn't work, python...

Comment: Well, of course it's trivial to do in bash or python, I am interested in native radare solution. It's a shame to pass text to bash/python and back (and takes a lot of typing): just typing 'while' is already longer than most of radare commands :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@@` is indeed for flags [not only those that are prefixed with `sym.` though].
It looks like you need to use the `@@=` iterator.

For example:
`` px 4 @@=`afl~[0]` ``

Comment: Does `@@` also do a temporary seek? Why is it not `px 4 @ @@=`afl~[0]`?